# Difference between Spring-JPA and Spring-Data-JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Difference between Spring-JPA and Spring-Data-JPA and I don't mean JPA the specification . 
I am new to JPA and Spring. 
While integrating Hibernate with Spring as JPA provider i came across two Spring project. 
Please clarify the difference as well as relationship between 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jpa 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa 
I found out **spring-data-jpa** contains JpaRepository interface which i intend to use but then what is the use of **spring-jpa**.

Comment: to freely quote star wars, *those are not the artifacts you are looking for*. Spring JPA has been long time superseded/merged into Spring ORM (which is part of the Spring Framework). Which provides basic integration for JPA within your application like configuring an `EntityManagerFactory`, transaction managers and `OpenEntityManagerInView[Filter|Interceptor]`. Spring Data JPA is an abstraction layer for JPA based repositories saving you from writing the nitty gritty repetitive JPA stuff.

Comment: Should i be using Spring-ORM
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.1.4.RELEASE
Will I still need Hibernate or any other JPA provider with Spring-ORM ?

Comment: Spring, as with other things, only provides wrappers, it isn't a JPA implementation. Which is also explained in the reference guide.

Comment: Thanks you.
The name "Spring-ORM" confused me .

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the artifcat dates that is something really old - 2008. You should not worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, Spring Data is predecessor for Spring Framework: JPA.